# Registering .OCX and DLL files using VB6 Package and Deployment Wizard on Win 2008 R2

Tags: vb6, installation, registry

I am trying to install a VB app using an installer created by package and deployment wizard (installer created on Win 2003). The installer installs fine and I see that dependencies (ocx and dll files) are installed in the sysWOW64 folder instead of the system32 folder (since the app is 32 bit). However when I run the app, it cannot find the ocx or dll dependencies. What am I missing?

Comment: Please consider switching to Inno Setup or NSIS; no one deploying an app on modern OSes should be using the ancient PDW. Watch your installer via Process Explorer, is it launching regsvr32 correctly?

Comment: InnoSetup is a legacy scripted installer and as deprecated as the PDW.  Regsvr32 is not supposed to be used for deployment, it is much better to create an MSI package that handles the component registration properly.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371608(VS.85).aspx for cautions about self registration.

Answer (score 0):

Is your setup.exe triggering elevation?

It is possible to end up with per-user registration in virtualized locations instead of typically-expected HKLM registration.

Have you gone in and checked for the registration entries using RegEdit?

Answer (score 0):

try to adjust the compatibility in your EXE application.., right click the appliacation dn goto compatibility then check the run this program in the compatibility mode and also check the  run as administrator..,

if the problem still excess drag and drop the dll/ocx to regsvr32 in the system32 folder

Answer (score 0):

It's likely to be something to do with the permissions and priviliges used when the installer ran.

Just use a modern MSI based installer like Installshield. It will save you a lot of bother.